# Constructor vs init

Tags: java, objective-c, class, constructor

In `Java`, a new object is created through the calling of a constructor. The counterpart in `Objective-C` is the pairing of the `+alloc` and the `-init` calls. Are there any significant differences between the role of constructors in Java and the combination of the `+alloc` and `-init` methods in Objective-C?

Comment: closed because it's a duplicate of the question referred to above...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: no worries, and you're absolutely welcome!